# Timeline (HTML, CSS, Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make timeline like this (horizontal on desktop, but vertical on mobile devices)

[image: desktop ver.]

mobile ver. like this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-21-with-images-and-responsive

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: you should attempt first..

Answer (score 2):

**Use Following Code**

For horizontal Timeline this is best

https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html